# How to print a work in string containing specific characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

For this string:

```
string ='fieldnameRelated_actions/fieldnamedatatypeRESOURCE_LIST</datatype><values><value>![CDATA[nprod00123456]/value>value>![CDATA[nprod00765432]]/valuevaluesfield'
```

I want to print `nprod00123456` and `nprod00765432`
or word like: `nprodxxxxxxxx`

How can this be done in Python?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here. 
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the following regular expression:

```
import re    

text = "fieldnameRelated_actions/fieldnamedatatypeRESOURCE_LIST![CDATA[nprod00123456]/value>value>![CDATA[nprod00765432]]/valuevaluesfield"
print re.findall(r'(nprod\d+)', text)
```

Giving you:

```
['nprod00123456', 'nprod00765432']
```

This works by finding any `nprod` in the text followed by one or more digits.

---

Alternatively, without `re`, it might be possible as follows:

```
print ['nprod{}'.format(t.split(']')[0]) for t in text.split('nprod')[1:]]
```